# I am using spring-data-couchbase , but the Query creation from method names does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, couchbase, nosql

I am using spring-data-couchbase , but the Query creation from method names is not work. following is my code:

spring-couchbase.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
             xmlns:couchbase="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase"
             xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase/spring-couchbase.xsd">

    <couchbase:couchbase bucket="comment" host="192.168.20.118,192.168.20.71" />
    <couchbase:template/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.david.comment.core.repository" />

</beans:beans>
```

Repository:

```
public interface CommentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<CommentDoc, String> {
    public Page<CommentDoc> findByUserId(String userId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Domain:

```
@Document
@Data
public class CommentDoc {

    @Id
    private String id;

    /**
     * 话题
     */
    @Field
    private String topicId;

    /**
     * 用户ID
     */
    @Field
    private String userId;
}
```

Test:

```
    @Test
    public void testFindByC1() {
        Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10);
        Page<CommentDoc> comments = commentRepository.findByUserId("user01", pageable);
        for(CommentDoc commentDoc : comments) {
            logger.debug("doc: {}", commentDoc);
        }
    }
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown query param: user01
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.ViewBasedCouchbaseQuery.execute(ViewBasedCouchbaseQuery.java:47)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:371)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.ViewPostProcessor$ViewInterceptor.invoke(ViewPostProcessor.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.findByUserId(Unknown Source)
    at com.runmit.comment.core.test.CommentRepositoryTest.testFindByC1(CommentRepositoryTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
```

Please someone help me! How can I resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this, but just went through it.  The Couchbase stuff doesn't seem to support everything offered in the other Spring Data repositories.

1. You have to add a production view called commentdoc/byUserId (in development view design document name = commentdoc and viewname = byUserId).  Don't forget to publish.  Something like (fix classname):

   ```
   function (doc, meta) {
       if(doc._class == "com.david.XXX.CommentDoc" && doc.userId){
           emit(doc.userID, null);
        }
    }
   ```
2. Change your repo signature from String userId to Query userId
3. Pass a Query object.  Something like:

   ```
   Query query = new Query();
   query.setKey(ComplexKey.of("useridofinteres="));
   commentRepository.findByUserId(query, pageable);
   ```

   [Full Details Here.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase)