# Multiple queries error when creating Couchbase views

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view, spring-data-couchbase

I am trying to create a view in couchbase. Below is my query,

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if (doc._class == "com.abc.xyz.Account" && doc.accountId) {
    emit(doc.accountId, null);
  }
}
```

However, I am getting below exception:

```
{"error":"Error, you cannot issue more than one query at once. Please remove all text after the semicolon closing the first query."}
```

Not sure what is the issue with the query. Tried searching for the solution but couldn't find any.

Comment: Please provide more details about versions of the libraries being used like couchbase and spring-data-couchbase.

Comment: I am running this query on couchbase query editor, couchbase version is 5.5.1. Also, the cb java client library version is 2.5.9 and spring-data-couchbase:3.0.9.

Answer (score 2):

The javascript function mentioned in the question appears to be a [Couchbase Map/Reduce View Engine](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/3.x/admin/Views/views-writing.html) definition. These can be queried using either SDK or REST API, and details are outlined in [View Querying](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/3.x/admin/Views/views-querying.html) section. In addition, the Map/Reduce View UI (same place where the map/reduce functions are defined) has some limited capability to query the view being defined.

The Couchbase Query UI is exclusively for N1QL/SQL++ queries. The function mentioned can be expressed in N1QL very easily:

```
CREATE INDEX ON mybucket(accountId) WHERE _class == "com.abc.xyz.Account";
```

So it would not be necessary to create Couchbase Map/Reduce views. And the above index can be queried, for example, as:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mybucket WHERE _class == "com.abc.xyz.Account";
```

I'm sure the above function you mention is just an example, and the actual use case is more complex, but the general approach still holds true. It's a good idea to start by using declarative tool (N1QL) as it is much simpler to use.

There are many useful resources for this such as the [N1QL Tutorial](https://query-tutorial.couchbase.com) to help start using N1QL. This would be the best starting point for most use cases.

Comment: thanks SM3. I am trying to use use spring data out of box feature in my project. For example, I have an AccountRepository interface that extends CouchbaseRepository. I have method definition called findByAccountId . However, in one of the threads, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620182/i-am-using-spring-data-couchbase-but-the-query-creation-from-method-names-does), it is mentioned that I will need a backing view to make it work. Also, the following two other ways work for me.

Comment: Optional<Account> accountList = accountRepository.findById(accountId);
JsonDocument test = bucket.get(accountId.toString());                                            I am not sure on what's wrong with above query to create views.